# Prism Navigation in Xamarin Forms - MasterDetailPage

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, prism, master-detail

I have a master detail page setup using Prism 6.3 pre-2, I've finally got it working as I expected for navigating to "detail" pages; so the hamburger button shows the slide drawer and I have a simple ListView bound to the ViewModel, I list some items, and I use the NavigateCommand to navigate correctly.

Now, the expected behaviour (in Android), is when you've navigated to other items in the slide-out menu, you should be able to use the hardware back button to navigate back to the very first "detail" page shown.

For example, say your app has this setup, and the items listed are Inbox, Drafts, and Sent. The default view is going to be whatever you decide is the default detail view, in this example, it will most likely be Inbox. So if I navigate to Sent, and then press back, it should go back to Inbox, also, if I go to Sent -> Drafts, and then press back, it should go back to Inbox, as this is the default starting point, if you then press back again, the app should exit. At the moment, using Prism navigation, no matter what page you navigate to using this setup, it will exit straight away.

Please note, I have set it up correctly, I essentially have something like this (as an exmaple):

`await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("RootPage/BaseNavigationPage/InboxPage");`

When I navigate to say another page like Sent, the relative URI is like so:

`"BaseNavigationPage/SentPage"`

Now, when back is pressed, it should go back to the InboxPage, I'm not sure how this can be fixed... Brain...???

In addition to this, there is one other unexpected behaviour that is missing.
If I want to show a modal page whilst using a Master Detail Page, it doesn't work as any app written by Google does... This is easy to see if you open any google app that has this layout. If you show a modal window for say Settings, it pops up, has the navigation title set and a back arrow, basically looks exactly the same as if you've navigated one step further down like:

```
"RootPage/BaseNavigationPage/InboxPage/EmailPage"
```

However, I expected this functionality to be available if I did the following:

```
"BaseNavigationPage/SettingsPage", useModalNavigation:true
```

If you simply play around with any Google made application you'll see these features, and these are what I expect and they feel natural.

Any help available to achieve this...? again...Brian...?

All of this should be simple, but it's proving not to be...

Answer (score 2):

To get the behavior you are wanting with the NavigationPage in a MasterDetailPage scenario, you must create a custom NavigationPage that implements INavigationPageOptions and set the ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation property to false.  This will kep the NavigationPage's navigation stack in place with each navigation operation.

As to your other "expected behavior" regarding modal navigation, your understandings about modal navigation are wrong.  Modal navigation does not provide a software back button.  Any time you want a software back button you must have the pages wrapped in a NavigationPage,